# Is there a way to optimize my daemon?

Tags: shell, systemd, daemon

I wrote this shell script, which changes my video and sound output to hdmi as soon as my monitor is connected. I activate it via systemd.

```
#!/bin/bash
intern=eDP1
extern=DP1

while true; do
    if xrandr | grep "$extern disconnected"; then
        xrandr --output "$extern" --off --output "$intern" --auto
        pactl set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
    else
        xrandr --output "$intern" --off --output "$extern" --auto
        pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo
    fi
    sleep 1;
done
```

Everything works as intended. Do you have any suggestions on how to optimize my Code?

Comment: It's readable, small and does what you need it to do. No need to "optimize" anything

Comment: The script looks good! Did you know about https://github.com/phillipberndt/autorandr ?

Comment: What are you optimizing for? Speed? Readability? Maintainability?

Comment: @FrederikDeweerdt No, thanks for showing me. It's written in python though, which lets me believe it would use up much more memory then other languages.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I just wanted to check if I'm unnecessarily using more cpu/ram than needed.

Comment: Without having your setup, my only other idea would be to see if there are hardware events that you could trigger the changes from.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can think about doing with this script (which I haven't tested as I'm not on a Unix system running X, nor do I have a HDMI monitor), apart from running it every single second (which sounds like overkill), is to apply the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) to it.  This would mean refactoring it so that it only calls `xrandr` and `pactl` in a single place in the loop (except for an extra `xrandr` call in the test):

```
#!/bin/sh

intern=eDP1
extern=DP1

while true; do
    if xrandr | grep -q -F -e "$extern disconnected"; then
        output_on=$intern
        output_off=$extern
        profile=analog
    else
        output_on=$extern
        output_off=$intern
        profile=hdmi
    fi

    if [ "$previous_profile" != "$profile" ]; then
        xrandr --output "$output_off" --off \
               --output "$output_on" --auto

        pactl set-card-profile 0 "output:$profile-stereo+input:analog-stereo"

        previous_profile=$profile
    fi

    sleep 1
done
```

This way, you only have to change the parameters to the calls to `xrandr` and `pactl` in one place and you don't have to remember updating multiple lines of code.

Since the script is not using any `bash`-specific features, I've also changed the shell to `/bin/sh` which may be a more light-weight shell than `bash`.  You may want to point it to the `dash` shell executable explicitly.

The `grep` call is fixed in such a way that it does not produce any output (`-q`) and so that it does a string comparison rather than a regular expression match (`-F`).  The `-e` tells `grep` that the next thing on the command line is the search pattern.  It is generally good to use `-e` if the first thing in the pattern is a variable expansion, as a value starting with a `-` may confuse the utility.

I've also made sure that the `xrandr` and `pactl` calls are *not* made if the value of the `profile` variable does not change between iterations.